# Using variable as array keys

Tags: php, arrays

I've got function like this:

```
for($j; $j < $l; $j++) {
    if ($type != 'a'){
        $coords = array('x'=>$points[$j]['x'],'y'=>$points[$j]['y']);
    } else {
        $coords = array('x'=>$points[$j]['loc']['x'],'y'=>$points[$j]['loc']['y']);
    }

    //other wird math operations for ex.
    $x = 100 + $coords['x'];
    $y = 200 + $coords['y'];
}
```

And this condition is in loop which is iterating over 1 mio. times each time so performance is very important, and all records in points collection are this type or this type, there can not be mixing between them.

So I would like somehow remove this condition and move it before loop starts. My idea is to use variable as array keys.

For example (Pseudo code):

```
if ($type != 'a'){
    $keyX = 'x';
    $keyY = 'y';
} else {
    $keyX = ['loc']['x'];
    $keyY = ['loc']['y'];
}

for($j; $j < $l; $j++) {
    $x = 100 + $points[$j]$keyX;
    $y = 100 + $points[$j]$keyY;
}
```

I know that above code will not work, but I want to show my general conception. Is it possible et all in php? Or maybe there is other solution.

**EDIT:**

The biggest problem here is that, one array is multidimentional

Comment: Your question is not clear? can you put some array what you have and what you want as an expected output or something else in addition with theses?

Comment: How do you add 100 to an array? `$x = 100 + $coords;` This should throw you a: `Unsupported operand types`

Comment: @anantkumarsingh what isn't clear for you? i showed example code, showed what I want to achieve...I cant show you exact data becouse of clear reasons..

Comment: @Rizier123 och sorry... my mistake.. edited and fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working but unpractical approach: :)

```
$l = 1;
$points[0]['x'] = '0x';
$points[1]['x'] = '1x';
$points[1]['loc']['x'] = '1-loc-x';
$points[0]['loc']['x'] = '0-loc-x';
$type = 'a';
$x = '';

if ($type != 'a') {
    $key = "['x']";
}else{
    $key = "['loc']['x']";
}
for($j=0;$j<$l;$j++){
    $x .= eval('echo $points['.$j.']'.$key.';');
    echo $x;
}
```

result 0-loc-x

**EDIT1** if you are really faced the task with such conditions, you should think about creating array in reverse order of keys $points[loc][x]. Then your code will be easy:

```
$keyX = $type != 'a ? &$points['x'] : &$points['loc']['x'];

for($j; $j < $l; $j++) {
    $x = 100 + $keyX[$j];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your approach, in fact this is more accurate answer for my question, so I marked it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just put the if statement around the for loop and then decide, through which loop you want to go, e.g.

```
if($type != "a") {
    for($j; $j < $l; $j++)
        $x = 100 + $points[$j]['y'];
} else {
    for($j; $j < $l; $j++)
        $x = 100 + $points[$j]['loc']['y'];
}
```

No need to assign it also to a variable and then only access one array element.

Comment: Yeah... It can be done like that, but function in loop is very complex, so maintenance would be poor, but +1 for idea

Comment: @Krystian Then show your full function if it isn't like over 50 lines, which would then definitely be a problem in your code logic.

Comment: I can't do this for legal reasons. If this will be the only answer I will accept it as option for this situation.

Comment: @Krystian Then it is getting difficult to help you. And from the code shown in your code I only see this option to only have one if statement check

Comment: yeah I think so too, so anyway...I would wait for any other ideas, and after while I will accept your answer. Thanks mate! :)